# Reading xml in Smarty template

Tags: xml, parsing, templates, rss, smarty

In my smarty template, I have this assigning...

```
{assign var="feeds" value="-RSS FEED LINK-"}
```

How do I parse the variable `$feeds` and print the values in each tag - in the smarty template?

Comment: You aren't looking for this answer, but I wouldn't do it in the smarty template. PHP templating systems are great for separating business logic with presentation, which I think you'd be violating. I would recommend that you parse your RSS feed in PHP and assign the outcome to smarty to iterate and display the values.

Answer (score 0):

This should load the XML into an Object and print it:

```
{assign var="feeds" value="-RSS FEED LINK-"}
{$feeds|@simplexml_load_string|@print_r}
```

But loke Paul said in the comments, I would suggest to do the assignment in PHP and then use smarty to just walk the object.